# MSSQL PHP cannot delete rows

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, rows

First of all sorry for my English.
Im trying to delete / insert some rows to a MSSQL Table but i get no error but it just doesnt work. But when I do a SELECT statement it works as well.

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect("SERVERNAME", "username", "password") or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$selected = mssql_select_db("myDB", $dbhandle) or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
mssql_query("DELETE dbo.import");
```

The server SQL INSTANCE is installed on my local computer and I'm the Administrator of this SQL Server but the Webserver is on another PC.
I created the user and I assigned the role **db_owner**
When I try the same query on another SQL Server, it works.

I also tryed:

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect("SERVERNAME", "username", "password") or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$selected = mssql_select_db("myDB", $dbhandle) or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
$result = mssql_query("DELETE dbo.import; SELECT * FROM dbo.import;");
$sqlRows = array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $sqlRows[] = $row;
}
echo sizeof($sqlRows);
```

and the echo return 0, but when I check from SSMS the records are still there.

```
 DELETE SCHEMA.TABLE; SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE;
```

returns 0 rows. And then I try again

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.import;
```

returns 26 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT 2

The solution was a not committed transaction. See comments...

#### EDIT

My answer is not right to the point... I must admit, that I never used `DELETE` without `FROM`, but this works obviously:

```
create table #tbl(id int);
insert into #tbl values(1),(2);
select * from #tbl;
delete #tbl;
select * from #tbl;
drop table #tbl;
```

I let the answer there due to the comments...

Comment: I have the same problem when I try to insert new rows.

Comment: when i run $result = mssql_query("INSERT INTO dbo.import ([Ticket Issue Date]) VALUES (GETDATE()); SELECT * FROM dbo.import"); i get 27 ROWS but when i check from SSMS i still have 26 ROWS

Comment: @djsony90 The most common reason for such a behavior is either a transaction rollback or your command is running against the wrong server/database/table... (or your SSMS-check is not connected to the right database. Might help to close all query windows and re-open them as they keep their connection even when you disconnect and re-connect)

Comment: @djsony90 I dont think mssql_query can run more than 1 query.

Comment: @Shnugo I just deleted 2 rows from SSMS and when i try from PHP now I have 24 rows, so the server / database / table is OK.

Comment: @djsony90 OK, if you insert the row and you get it back with select and than it's gone ... - I'd guess on a transaction which is not commited...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I just found the answer searching on the Web.
There was a rollback as mentioned from **Shnugo** and adding `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;` at the beginning of the query it solve the problem.

Thank you